# Git hook to push to another repo

Tags: git, hook

I've got a GIT hook question...

I've 2 repos. One of them (the Repo B) is unknown to users.

**Repo A :** the "origin" repo on which I need add a custom pre-receive hook is responsible for pushing to Repo B.

**Repo B :** the Repo A clone on which a hook can possibly reject pushes.

What I really need is that the push to Repo A is rejected if the hook that push to Repo B is rejected.

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic